# SUM FLOAT SQL add set number value

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sum

and now the sum is very correct

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(price), 2) FROM items;
```

but, is it possibile to add a set number value to sum?

for example:

> item 1: 11.81
>
> item 2: 21.85
>
> item 3: 11.85
>
> total: 45,51

if I want add always 5.00 at the sum, how can I do it? (50,51)

thank you

Comment: Is this not working??
"SELECT ROUND(SUM(price), 2) + 5 FROM items;"

Comment: I tried, and work perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of [`ROUND`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions142.htm#SQLRF00698) in that context is very strange. May I guess this is because your prices are expressed with more than 2 decimal?

If it is the case, the correct way of doing it would be:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(price) + cst, 2) FROM items;
--                        ^^^
--               your constant value
```

That way, you could add a constant with as much as decimal as your prices -- and the result sum being rounded.

This is especially true if your prices are expressed as `BINARY_FLOAT` instead of `NUMBER`. A thing I wouldn't encourage though. In that unfortunate eventuality, you should postfix your constant literal by either `f` of `d` to prevent some implicit conversion during processing (see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51048)

Comment: No, the prices are the ones I put in the first post (11:50 or 950.32 etc), but
 
    SELECT SUM (column_name) FROM table_name;    
 
did not work, I was an invalid from the values in oracle

I do not want you round the result, but that is the precise result including decimals (only 2)

Comment: yes ROUND in that context is very strange but I don't understand, why without ROUND the sum is not correct.

Comment: Yes, in my database oracle, the price are expressed as datatype NUMBER(5,2) (precision 5, scale 2). wait I tried this

"SELECT SUM(price) + 5 AS total FROM table1"

and work PERFECTLY.... before not. thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can dd like this

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(price), 2) + 5 FROM items
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(price), 2) + 5.0 
FROM items;
```